# how to improve java web services response?

Tags: java

In my application, I'm showing a home page to every user when they logged in. This page contains images, videos and profile pictures and some other data like Pinterest. This takes long time to load all these things. So how to improve the response speed.

Comment: Show only what is directly seen in the page and as user scrolls down load new content. But this is not related to java directly.

Comment: you could make use of a caching layer.

Comment: Thanks to all. How to use caching layer. I don't know any thing about it. Will u suggest any tutorials for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well These are the general practices you follow to make response faster from server :-

1) Send Response as JSON as its light weight.

2) Load home page which has minimum content. Then makes the ajax call (to retrieve the main content of page like data in grid) while page load this makes the user to feel as faster response as base pages has been loaded

3) Use asynchronous calls wherever possible like loading images from third party etc.

4) Send minimum data from server wherever it is possible as it takes less time for travelling.
If you are doing some kind of stuff that can be done on client side without security security, should go for it.